# Error Adding markers in seaborn pairplot in python

Tags: python, seaborn

I want to add markers seaborn but i got an error

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/vaksakalli/datasets/master/diamonds.csv')
df = df.sample(n=300, random_state=123)
sns.pairplot(data=df,vars=['carat','depth','table','price'], hue='cut', markers=["+","o", "s", "D","x"])
```

[image]

My Expected output :
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As the error clearly indicates, you cannot mixed filled and line markers.
See the list of markers here:
You need to either choose markers that are filled (e.g.

> ```
> "o"   m02     circle
> "v"   m03     triangle_down
> "^"   m04     triangle_up
> "<"   m05     triangle_left
> ">"   m06     triangle_right
> "8"   m11     octagon
> "s"   m12     square
> "p"   m13     pentagon
> "P"   m23     plus (filled)
> "*"   m14     star
> "h"   m15     hexagon1
> "H"   m16     hexagon2
> "X"   m24     x (filled)
> "D"   m19     diamond
> "d"   m20     thin_diamond
> ```

or markers that are not filled

> ```
> "1"   m07     tri_down
> "2"   m08     tri_up
> "3"   m09     tri_left
> "4"   m10     tri_right
> "+"   m17     plus
> "x"   m18     x
> ```

but not both.

For instance, your code works with

```
markers=["o", "s", "D","X","v"]
```